# Как на Андроид уведомление по расписанию сделать

Tags: java, android

Хочу сделать приложение с уведомлением каждый или через день для. Как это проще реализовать?

Notifications уже знаю как отправлять, в php просто было cron.
 Здесь как заставить выполнять программу например каждый понедельник, или каждый день какие функции для этого используют?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться `JobScheduler`.
Подробное описание, как создать задачу и запланировать ее, можно прочесть [здесь](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html)